# Assign the pointer of one class object to another class object c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, polynomials

so I am very new to C++ programming so I apologize beforehand if I am asking something trivial. My assignment is to add, multiply and evaluate polynomials where each term of a specified polynomial is represented by a Node class with private variables: double coefficient, int power and Node *next.

```
class Node{
private:
double coef;
int power;
Node *next;
public: blah
}
```

The head to that linked list (for each polynomial), is to be stored in an array of Poly objects where the only private variable in my Poly class is Node *head.

```
class Poly{
private:
Node *head;
public:poly functions;
}
```

The user is to select the polynomial they want to work with by selecting an element from my polynomial array, and this will give the head to the selected polynomial.

```
poly_array[n];
```

However my issue now is that the element of this array is of object Poly and I want to make it of class Node so I can actually extract its contents of the class and use this method to transverse through the nodes of the selected polynomial(s). 
This is the code I have tried to implement to make this work but my function call of convert poly returns garbage. I am lost as to what method I should try next. Thank you in advance. 
This is where I try to first transverse a polynomial to display its contents.

```
void init_polydisplay(vector<Poly*> polynomial_array, int numofpolys)
{
Poly *polyobject;
Node *polyhead;

for (int n = 0; n < numofpolys; n++)
{
    temp3.getnodehead();
    polyhead=polyobject->convertPoly(polynomial_array[n]);
}
}
```

My attempt at trying to return Node* versus just the head of the polynomial.

```
Node* Poly::convertPoly(Poly* tmp)
{
return (Node *) tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `get_head()` function in `Poly`

```
class Poly{
private:
Node *head;
public:
 Node * get_head()
    {
      return head;
    }
};
```

and use it this way:

```
polyhead = polynomial_array[n]->get_head();
```

Comment: I appreciate your help greatly. This is exactly what I needed! This should put me on the right path.